# how to download google trend csv file automatically to particular direcotory and rename it using php code

Tags: php, csv, google-trends

Is There Any Way to get google trends data/csv file in php array by using url with passing parameters like: keywords, date, etc.

if it is possible then provide the code to integrate google trends so that we can pass the url and google trend csv file is automatically download to directory as we pre-define.

Also provide code to automatically login into gmail account by passing user name and password if it is required to get csv file.

currently we get error below:

"An error has been detected
You have reached your quota limit. Please try again later."

if not possible then is there any paid api for google trends that allow user to put keywords and date and other fields and download google trends csv file